# Seaborn displot. How to control font size and rotation for each subplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I am plotting multiple distributions via the 'col' parameter and trying to change the fontsize and rotation for xticks but it will only take effect on the last subplot. How do I make it so that it changes for both subplots?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `tick_params` for all axes with:

```py
g.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=5)
```

Or iterate over the Axes in your [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) object `g`:

```py
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
  ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=5)
```

Comment: labelsize should be with lowercase "L". Other than that both proposals work